bias in jetpack compose ConstraintLayout
For example, I want the right side to align with Image's start when the Text width is less than screen's width, and the Text will wrap automatically when the Text's width is more than screen's width ,I use ConstraintLayout, but it does not have a bias property, so that when the Text's width is less than screen, the Text position will in center displayed instead of next to the Image's start
ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            val (column, image) = createRefs()

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .constrainAs(column) {
                        start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 15.dp)
                        end.linkTo(image.start, margin = 8.dp)
                        width = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
                    }

            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Div",
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontSize = 18.sp
                )
                Text(
                    text = "hello,world!",
                    fontSize = 14.sp
                )

                Text(
                    text = "10:12",
                    fontSize = 11.sp
                )
            }

            Image(
                painterResource(id = R.mipmap.stock2), "",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(40.dp)
                    .constrainAs(image) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = 12.dp)
                    }
            )
        }

When I don't remove this line of code
start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 15.dp)

Text’s width less than screen‘s width，The Text's position is going to be centered, but when I remove this line of code, when the Text's width is more than screen's width it's going to be out of the screen instead of wrapping，How can I solve this problem? ConstraintLayout has no bias attribute, and when all left and right are restricted, how can I make it tilt to the right

Instead of
start.linkTo(parent.start, margin = 15.dp)
end.linkTo(image.start, margin = 8.dp)

You should use this function which sets both start and end constraints and has a bias argument:
linkTo(
  start = parent.start,
  end = image.end,
  startMargin = 15.dp,
  endMargin = 8.dp,
  bias = 0.5f,
)

